# Saving Process State by Writing Pages to Blocks

Tags: operating-systems

Why don’t operating systems save process state (registers, page tables, pages) by writing state to storage in blocks? Wouldn’t this allow for a seamless restoration of state when the process needs to continue? Specifically, in graphics intensive processes (ie video games), wouldn’t this make load time way quicker?

Comment: Uh, they do? The blocks are called pages. I don't understand the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Operating systems already do that when they need to.  See, e.g., https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Context_switch, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_paging, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_control_block, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_memory.

More specifically, if there is plenty of RAM, there is no need to write anything to storage.  You can keep it in RAM, and save registers etc. to RAM, and switch to a different process.  Then, when you're ready to switch back, everything is already in RAM.  So, operating systems only save to storage (SSD, hard disk, etc.) when necessary, i.e., when they're running out of available space in RAM.  Most operating systems today do that via [paging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_paging), but some older operating systems used [swapping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_memory#Address_space_swapping).

Some operating systems use [hibernation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hibernation_(computing)) to save the state of all processes to storage/disk when they shut down or go to sleep.  This is similar to what you mention, but is done for all processes, not just one process.

Comment: Many modern operating systems also have a "hibernate mode".

Comment: @Pseudonym, good point, I've added that to the answer.